# Parsing arabic/chinese/japanese rss feeds with java

Tags: java, parsing, utf-8, rss, character-encoding

I'm writing a rss feed parser with java and I've encountered a problem while parsing feed that have arabic/chinese/japanese characters. [Example feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/video/bilahodood)

When I print them I just get sets of question marks "?????? ?? ????? ??".

They end up in my database (mysql, connected by hibernate, has utf8 set as encoding) also like that.

This the part of the code that is responsible for getting the title from a feed:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Node channelNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel").item(0);

NodeList channelList = channelNode.getChildNodes();

for (int i = 0; i < channelList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node element = channelList.item(i);

    String name = element.getNodeName();

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
     rssName = element.getTextContent();
     break;
    }
}
```

How to get the proper characters into the database ?
When I copy them from the feed and insert manulally into the db its ok.

Thanx

UPDATE:
Putting additional lines in my hibernate config fixed the issue:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>  
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
```

Comment: You do have fonts installed to print those characters?

Comment: @rubenvdg: if there were no fonts for those characters, one would have seen empty white squares with a black border or in specific applications (some webbrowsers) the [unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), certainly not question marks.

Comment: @BalusC: I thought it depends on the context, if I'm not mistaken, a linux terminal window will show question marks in certain cases. In any case, never mind my remark, I missed the last sentence about the "insert manually".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the MySQL JDBC URL in Hibernate configuration to include the following params:

```
jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Otherwise the MySQL JDBC driver will use the client platform default encoding.

Your DB encoding is totally fine since manual insert works apparently fine. XML is usually by default parsed as UTF-8, so that part is fine as well (unless explicitly otherwise specified in the XML declaration header which is likely not the case since that would be a mistake of the RSS feed server).

Comment: Yeah, you were right, I did not have that in my hibernate configuration :)

Comment: I already have these lines in hibernate.cfg.xml, my issue is not resolved. I use this example -> http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-rss-feed-example/

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the character encoding of the database is compatible with such characters. Most likely by configuring it to be UTF-8.

If the database character encoding can not handle a character, it gets converted to ?.

Most databases will have an overall default encoding and then allow per table and per column overrides.

You will also need to ensure that you are parsing in incoming stream correctly (i.e. as UTF-8 or whatever encoding it specifies).

Answer (score -1):

It's clearly an encoding problem.
You should try to decode the RSS stream using the UTF-8 charset.

Comment: No, he should not. If a different character set is specified in the XML header, forcing the XML parser to use UTF-8 will for sure corrupt the data.